# Vim is displaying medium dash as �~@~S and long dash as �~@~R

Tags: vim, character-encoding, vimrc

I'm using `vim` on a shared Bluehost server. When I try to type `—`, Vim inserts `�~@~R`. And when I try to type `–`, Vim inserts `�~@~S`.

The problem is not specific to any particular file. It seems to happen in every file.

I tried logging out and using `vim` outside the server, and this time I could type medium and long dashes with no problem. So the problem is with Bluehost.

Does anyone know a solution? I suspect it involves adding something to the `.vimrc` file.

More details:

It only happens in Vim, not the command line.

I'm not using a graphical vim.

If I type :lang I get 'Current language: "C"'.

If I call vim with LC_ALL=C vim foo then the problem still happens.

**Edit:** I've found that if I enter `set encoding=utf-8` then the problem is solved, at least temporarily.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some details. Is this only in vim or do you also see it on the command line? Is this a graphical environment? A graphical vim? What is the output of `locale`?

Comment: Open vim and run: `:lang`. Could you share the output? [edit] the question, don't add it in the comments. Also, does this happen if you call vim like this: `LC_ALL=C vim foo`?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think the solution is to change the Vim's encoding by opening .vimrc, entering

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

and then saving the file.

Comment: You cal always run `:set fileencoding` to see the buffers encoding. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

put that into your .vimrc

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

Like this vim.stackexchange says in [Specify UTF-8 encoding in Vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17326/10492)